# Which vector is closer to normality in R

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I would like to know if there is a test implemented in R that I can use to compare several vectors and indicate which one is closer to a normal distribution? I am specifically looking for a number that would indicate that, not visual inspection. For example: comparing `a`, `b` and `c` I know that `b` is closer to a normal distribution, but how would I capture that automatically in R.

```
a <- runif(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
c <- rpois(100, 10)
```

Comment: The primary difference is that Uniform is platykurtotic and Poisson is right skewed (higher ,75th order statistic than expected for its s.d.). These might best be investigated with third or fourth moments. I think the question should be made more specific than it currently stands. Suggest migration to CrsooValidated.come. Once you know what methods and terminology fits your needs then you can do search of R packages.

Comment: Do you want to compare sample with different sizes? What is a sample of the sizes you have? If I correctly understood it is your main concern.

Comment: Within comparisons they should all be the same sample size, but the sample size will differ among different comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tests.  Here are two: Shapiro Test and KS test:

```
set.seed(7)
a <- runif(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
c <- rpois(100, 10)

ks.test(a, "pnorm")
ks.test(b, "pnorm")
ks.test(c, "pnorm")

shapiro.test(a)
shapiro.test(b)
shapiro.test(c)
```

A significant value indicates that the distribution is significantly different than normal.  Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test